# How hide src url of iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

How hide src url of loaded iframe, is it possible?

Maybe there is a secret?

Is it possible to upload html to cache in iframe and after hide url?

Comment: Not possible. If it's being displayed in a browser, the user can/will be able to extract ANYTHING from it.

Answer (score 1):

Another good feature is to hide the location paths of your important scripts. I found a great npm plugin for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/location-hide

This works also for php href, src, content it will use everything inside src=""

It turns

```
<script src="test/folder/sample.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="test/stylesheet/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

into

```
<script src="TNANIuTOLZfmLYwaPDIYhcZDVOWKodqYhysaTeQHFPDhYlDLCOtxZqYmkKAhaSwSgbsYOWlpBzVSBtMZKSfwRqvPSqWVlBBuzHR" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="gyXeFnOEvZbgTjLvdZRnsyrfhaXqffkDjcdATTouqpIenCalLRXKamuXEtiKbPGCsNrdQIaqTMTNWsLyLFuxygKytaruWzSjKYMq" rel="stylesheet">
```

And it generate new jquery include codes like this to include your scripts with javascript in a external file

```
$('[src=\'TNANIuTOLZfmLYwaPDIYhcZDVOWKodqYhysaTeQHFPDhYlDLCOtxZqYmkKAhaSwSgbsYOWlpBzVSBtMZKSfwRqvPSqWVlBBuzHR\']').attr("src", "test/folder/sample.js")  
$('[href=\'gyXeFnOEvZbgTjLvdZRnsyrfhaXqffkDjcdATTouqpIenCalLRXKamuXEtiKbPGCsNrdQIaqTMTNWsLyLFuxygKytaruWzSjKYMq\']').attr("src", "test/stylesheet/perfect-scrollbar.css")
```

Also I would suggest you that you include all of your external javascript codes in 1 single js file. This file you place in the root of your index file that you can make this

```
<script src="./allinone_external_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then make right htaccess that nobody can acces this file. You can also make a fake import script for the source code that every body can see. But this file is only a redirect for the real external js file. you make this multiple times as example + use other obfuscation tools. This will protect you from people searching exploits with your javascript codes. I know its no big deal and maybe you can see the jquery include codes if you know how. But anyway it´s a great protection.

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing isn't possible, but you can encrypt the URL so it looks like the example below:

```
src="/my-page.php?a=x3d!evIc2HwXyny3JmcgLSvNwdy"
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What does that source attribute do?

Answer (score -1):

You can do ...:

1. `.html` file

   ```
   <script src="jquery" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
2. `.htaccess`

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^jquery?$ file_url/test.js?v=1.1.3 [NC,L]
   ```

Comment: No, that does not "hide" anything. Additionally, your example code doesn't even contain any iframe